# animation linked to different skeleton

Tags: rigging, armature

None of the animations of my goku model in the dota 2 model editor work. In the model editor I can see that there are 2 skeletons. The animations work on one of the skeletons, but that skeleton has no effect on the mesh, so it doesn't do anything.

[image: goku in dota 2 model editor with 2 skeletons]

When I first open the model in blender and then import the animation, the animation works and I have this setup:

[image]

But, when I do it the other way around, first import the animation and then the model I get this:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: attached blender files as mentioned in the comments.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52341

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52342

Comment: Hard to tell, I think you should upload your file

Comment: Hi. Please upload any images using the built-in image uploader as a) this prevents the answer being less clear should external links break and b) this shows the images inline. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: The images were more than 2MB